# Spring Integration: Always maintain order, after each processed file

Tags: spring-integration

I want to use SI for importing data into my application, reading it from XML files. I am fairly new to this technology but think, it might fit perfectly for my use case.

I necessarily need to watch for the order, which means when someone puts 5 files in it, I need to import some files first and some files after. This is crucial.

To make it simple let's say I have 2 types of files, say `A` and `B`.
I use a comparator to maintain the order:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="someId"
        directory="file:${folderPath}"
        filter="myFilter"
        auto-startup="true"
        comparator="myFileComparator">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

So far, so good, works like intenden. If I put 5 files in `A B B A B` it imports in the order `A A B B B`.

**But now consider following scenario**: When SI processed `A A B` and already began processing the second `B`, I decide to throw in another `A` file.
This means there are now the already-being-in-process-`B` left, plus the old-last-`B`, and my new-`A`. I expect that the next import shall be the new `A` after the already-being-in-process-`B` is done. Resulting in `A A B B A B`. (`A A B B` were already "set" before I added new files, and the `A B` afterwards needs to maintain the order).

But it is not. The result is `A A B B B A`. My `A` was simply thrown at the end, after the first batch of files.

I guess, Spring only fetches once, seeing `A A B B B` initially and puts this in an internal queue. And only after processing the whole queue, it looks again into the folder and redoes the process. Is this true?
How can I change this and achieve my desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need turn on `scan-each-poll` option:

```
 <xsd:attribute name="scan-each-poll" default="false">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    Set this flag if you want to make sure the internal queue is
                    refreshed with the latest content of the input directory on each poll.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:boolean xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>
```

Comment: Thanks! I used Spring 4.X and this feature is only available from 5 onwards. I am currently migrating to Spring 5 to use it and it seem to work as intetended :) But one strange thing happens: When I throw in my new `A` file, a `FileNotFoundException" is thrown by my comparator, pointing at the just processed (and relocated) file ... seems to work nonetheless though ...